# Using static method with IOC data access

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, static, inversion-of-control

I have an MVC project that uses the repository pattern. I am also using Ninject for the IOC containers. I am having a problem though with storing some cached values when the project loads.

In my Global.asax.cs I have:

```
...(some settings)
ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new NinjectControllerFactory());
....
...CustomDataCache.Configure();
```

and in my ControllerFactory I have the bindings I need:

```
_ninjectKernal.Bind<IDataContext>().To<DataContext>()
            .WithConstructorArgument("appNamekey", "Name of Data Application")
            .WithConstructorArgument("serverLocationNameKey", "Location of Application Server");
```

and in my CustomCache class I want to do something like:

```
private IDataContext _context;

private CustomDataCache(IDataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

public static void Configure(){
  System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache["NDECCategories"] = _context.GetNdecCategories();
```

I want to call Configure() statically from the global but how do i do this when I need an instance of the DataContext?

Thanks,

Comment: please explain "I want to call Configure() statically"... What do you want to achieve, and why? Do you want `Configure` to be a static method, so it can be called without an instance? If so, Global.asax seems the wrong way to set your context. Your context would have to be static too, so the static values are shared across all your users -- you would be over-writing context on every request for every user, but for all. That seems either wrong or wasteful. And, in that case, you don't benefit from using **IOC** with a static.

Answer (score 1):

Resolving dependencies varies.
For webforms...

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    <Dependency()>
    Public Property _userService As IUserService
```

For MVC

```
public UserController(IDataContextAsync context)
```

In reality, you shouldn't need to access your datacontext directly from your webapplication. You should be accessing the Service that has the IDataContextAsync setup in your constructor...

```
Public Class UserService
    Inherits Service(Of User)
    Implements IUserService

    Private ReadOnly _repository As IRepositoryAsync(Of User)

    Public Sub New(repository As IRepositoryAsync(Of User))
        MyBase.New(repository)
        _repository = repository
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass in the categories as a parameter in your `Configure` method?

```
var _context = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IDataContext>();
var categories = _context.GetNdecCategories();
CustomDataCache.Configure(categories);
```

Comment: If I put this in the GLobal.asax then I get a null reference exception on 

var categories = _context.GetNdecCategories();